# Dynamic list of filenames in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need Javascript code to retrieve a list(fill an array) of image filenames that reside in a   directory known to the code.  The directory is on the 'server side', so no 'sandbox' rules apply, but there is no actual server running, so I cant use actual server calls(This is just a browser-based app for me to display photos I have taken).

These files are accessible to the browser, my current program simply uses an array I have manually typed in with the filenames to display the images when needed.  I just need this array to be filled dynamically by the code instead of manually by me, since the files in the directory change often.

The program is in Javascript since the subjects of the pics are encoded in the filename as 4-letter codes and the program displays the images whose filenames contain the appropriate code.

To clarify- This is basically a program I have written to run on my home computer. It uses HTML,Javascript and Jquery to display information found on my computer.  At this point it is not accessible by the Internet, so no 'server' exists.  I list it as server-side merely because all the reponses to similar questions immediately go to the 'browser sandbox' issues about file access.  The program allows me to index photes I have and with a click of a button display all images of a particular person, place or animal for instance.
Thanks

Comment: You cannot do this with JavaScript (on the client side) alone.

Comment: javascript is a client side language and cannot retrieve server side files on its own

Comment: @Eonasdan to be correct, he is USING javascript as a client side language, and it won't be able to retrieve server files on its own.  Its not inherently a client-side language though, and environments may provide file manipulation APIs (ie Node)

Comment: if you can see a directory listing page, you can usually use ajax to fetch the listing, parse the HTML links, and thus obtain your list of images. you can also use a <file input type=file> in a build tool to turn folder contents into a JSON of image paths, and you can use FSO in IE browsers to obtain a listing.

Comment: You may want to consider looking into `http-server`, which is a super lightweight HTTP Server written for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: @Eonasdan, Dancrumb: I think he has a directory on the server which he wants to enumerate with clientside javascript, which should be possible.

Comment: @user248131: "*there is no actual server running*" - what is it then? There must be some kind of program that serves the files. And it should be able to serve the directory structure, otherwise it won't be possible. Please describe your exact setup on the serverside.

Comment: I have no server since this is not a 'web page' but is for my own use on my computer.  If it ever becomes a web page then I would have server running...

Comment: @ben336 there's no `node.js` tag here. The OP has tagged, and therefore assumed that the OP is referring to vanilla POJ. You can't get a directory listing from a **server** from a **client** side language without help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript can't scan a directory on the server

php(or someother serverside languages)+javascript is the only solution for dynamic file list

here is a simple php+js(ajax,json<-theproperway) example

images.html //works on most modern browsers.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>show images</title>
<script>
var
x=function(a,b,c){c=new XMLHttpRequest;c.open('GET',a);c.onload=b;c.send()},
display=function(){
 var myimages=JSON.parse(this.response);
 //now here u can show your images
 //myimages[0] is the first image....
}
window.onload=function(){
x('images.php',display);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

images.php // php 5

```
<?php
$a=json_encode(glob("path/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.png}", GLOB_BRACE));
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($a));
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); want to acces from crossdomain???
echo $a;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can get to the files with a browser, there is a server running somewhere that lets internet clients see that directory. Depending on what that server supports, you can just drop in a serverside script that, when "retrieved" by a client, does a dir listing for the directory it's in, ignoring its own filename, and then returns that list as a JSON array. For instance, if your server supported PHP, you'd use a file called `listing.php` with content:

```
<?php
  if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    $files = array();
    while (($entry = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
      // skip dir references and this file
      if($entry==="." || $entry===".." || $entry==="listing.php") continue;
      // add file to the list of files our client will want to care about
      $files[] = $entry;
    }
    // build a JSON-serialized object as response
    echo '{ "files" : [' . implode(',',$files) . ']}';
  }
?>
```

And then you fetch that list using a normal ajax call on your page (depending on your favourite JS framework the functions calls will differ. The pure JS way is to build an XMLHttpRequest object and opening a connection as `GET` for `listing.php`), turning the JSON serialized string that you get back into a normal JS object using one of the many JSON interpretation methods (the simplest being `var fileList = (new Function("return "+xhr.resonseText+";"))().files`), and then using that array in the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys.  I have been learning client-side web programming on my own, but it looks like to do what I want Server-side code will be necessary.  Sometimes you just cant get 'there' from 'here'.  Time to learn about servers,PHP and Ajax...So much to learn...